# Не отображается Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что текст Label не появляется. Всё работало отлично, пока я не добавил `label1.place(x=10, y=3)`.

Создавал текст вот так:

```py
label1 = Label(text="SzH", fg="#eee", bg="#505050")
label1.place(x=10, y=3)
```

вот весь код поскольку возможно проблема в том что текст находиться под линией сверху:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class Grip:
    ''' Makes a window dragable. '''
    def __init__ (self, parent, disable=None, releasecmd=None) :
        self.parent = parent
        self.root = parent.winfo_toplevel()

        self.disable = disable
        if type(disable) == 'str':
            self.disable = disable.lower()

        self.releaseCMD = releasecmd

        self.parent.bind('<Button-1>', self.relative_position)
        self.parent.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.drag_unbind)

    def relative_position (self, event) :
        cx, cy = self.parent.winfo_pointerxy()
        geo = self.root.geometry().split("+")
        self.oriX, self.oriY = int(geo[1]), int(geo[2])
        self.relX = cx - self.oriX
        self.relY = cy - self.oriY

        self.parent.bind('<Motion>', self.drag_wid)

    def drag_wid (self, event) :
        cx, cy = self.parent.winfo_pointerxy()
        d = self.disable
        x = cx - self.relX
        y = cy - self.relY
        if d == 'x' :
            x = self.oriX
        elif d == 'y' :
            y = self.oriY
        self.root.geometry('+%i+%i' % (x, y))

    def drag_unbind (self, event) :
        self.parent.unbind('<Motion>')
        if self.releaseCMD != None :
            self.releaseCMD()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x520+25+25")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    label1 = Label(text="SzH", fg="#eee", bg="#505050")
    label1.place(x=10, y=3)
    label2 = Label(text="Premium", fg="#eee", bg="yellow")
    label2.place(x=500, y=3)

    back = Frame(root, bg="grey")
    back.pack_propagate(0)
    back.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    top_Frame = Frame(back, bg="#505050")
    top_Frame.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", width=700, height=30)
    '''Would Be great if it could be specified to only be moved
    when dragging with the Frame above.'''
    grip = Grip(top_Frame)

    

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: А в чем проблема ? Просто не отображается label ?

Comment: не отображаеться текст

Comment: а есть код на гитхабе ?

Comment: не понял вопрос

Comment: если просто использовать label1 = Label(text="SzH", fg="#eee", bg="#505050")
label1.place(x=10, y=3) то все работает, а всявзке с моим кодом работать не хочет

Comment: В двух словах, что должен делать ваш скрипт?

Comment: пока что ничего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас создаются метки, потом поверх них создаются фреймы. Грубо говоря, объекты накладываются "стопкой" в порядке их размещения в окне. Если поменять порядок создания объектов, то метки станут видны:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x520+25+25")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.overrideredirect(1)

    back = Frame(root, bg="grey")
    back.pack_propagate(0)
    back.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    top_Frame = Frame(back, bg="#505050")
    top_Frame.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="nw", width=700, height=30)
    '''Would Be great if it could be specified to only be moved
    when dragging with the Frame above.'''
    grip = Grip(top_Frame)

    label1 = Label(text="SzH", fg="#eee", bg="#505050")
    label1.place(x=10, y=3)
    label2 = Label(text="Premium", fg="#eee", bg="yellow")
    label2.place(x=500, y=3)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также имеет смысл для меток родителем указать фрейм, поверх которого они размещаются:

```
label1 = Label(top_Frame, text="SzH", fg="#eee", bg="#505050")
label1.place(x=10, y=3)
label2 = Label(top_Frame, text="Premium", fg="#eee", bg="yellow")
label2.place(x=500, y=3)
```